# Rename / burninate the [fit] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, burninate-request

The [fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fit) tag (x236) is misused a lot.

[The wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/fit/info) says the following:

> Framework for Integrated Test, or "Fit", is an open-source tool for automated tests. The basic idea is to describe the tests as tables in HTML document, which can be created with any program which can save files in HTML format, such as word processors. Then Java fixtures need to be implemented to do actual tests based on the data in the HTML table.

However, most of questions tagged seem to be about *fitting* something into something:

- [Making Child Divs fit inside parent Div neatly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23591448/759064)
- [Css make an image fit in a 100% wide div](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19293034/759064)
- [Python - Fitting 2D rectangular data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14000988/759064)
- [How to fit a quadratic model knowing the maximum in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7917971/759064)

I did find some questions which seem to be valid for this tag:

- [Parsing nested objects in FIT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15269040/759064)
- [Checking code with FIT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14546208/759064)

I don't think this tag is any useful in its current state. I think it has to be renamed or maybe completely removed, if there're not enough questions which are really about the Framework. There're, actually, [only 14 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fit+java) which are tagged both [fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fit) and [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java).

Comment: Rename it to [misfit], because that's precisely what it has become.

Comment: Started cleaning in the tag. fit + java isn't a useful filter, but as a sometimes-user of Fit and Fitnesse I'll clear the tag from the questions it is misapplied on.

Comment: As mentioned below on my answer - all non-FIT related questions have been cleansed of the tag. 27 questions remain in the tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fit is the underlying framework (at least conceptually) for several related tools which also have tags, fitnesse (400 questions, 99 this year), fitnesse-slim (42 questions, 14 this year), selenium-fitnesse-bridge(16, 6 this year), and dbfit (27 questions, 13 this year).

A rename to `fit-framework` might be appropriate, but burnination or the proposed rename to `java-fit` would seem inappropriate.

Comment: I've cleaned all questions not having to do with the tag. Some got retagged for 'resize' or 'curve-fitting' if they were clearly within those domains.

Comment: Thank you for your work. Rename to `fit-framework` sounds good to me and should hopefully prevent constant misuse of this tag.

Comment: I just fixed 3 recent questions that used `fit` incorrectly.  It could use a rename.

Comment: I have cleaned up 2 misuses and moved all existing questions to a new [fit-framework] and adjusted the tag wikis accordingly.

Comment: @JasonMArcher I believe [fit-framework] should have included [fit] as a tag synonym.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the rep to make that happen.  At least there shouldn't be any future confusion.

Comment: Yeah, guess we'll be watching that tag for more answering opportunities so we can get the synonym added. Thanks for the reworking.

Answer (score -21):

Lets come up with a system where people can create their own tags to describe their questions. That way over time they can learn what tags work in getting their question the right attention from the right people who can answer it. The system would also have to allow for people to stop using tags that did not produce the results they wanted. The best thing about this system would be that it would require no intervention at all. It moderate it's self though natural selection.

(For those who don't know this the current system we have right now. At some point people add more information to the "tag" to codify its use. People who use the wrong tag simply don't get the correct attention to their question.)

Comment: That's going to end up like twitter hash-tags.

Comment: Exactly. It would "Work" with out the need for intervention like Twitter hashtags.

Comment: No, I mean if you allow people to come up with their own tags freely, it will get abused. Plus, how are people suppose to search for questions by tags when you don't know what they are? #TooManyTags

Comment: "That way over time they can learn what tags work in getting their question the right attention from the right people who can answer it.", or they can chose from the pre-existing list. Generally having the language tag is enough.

Comment: A vast number of the poor quality tags (and poorly tagged questions) come from users who come to SO to post one question, then never return. Sure, they might learn what tags work if they stick around, but they often won't stick around.

Comment: @Tanis.7x There is a rep requirement for creating new tags. For the users who have stuck around long enough to create them, I think we could encourage them to use different ones. If there ever is a reason to "Burninate" it's a sign of the threshold being too low or the community not wanting to get "positively" involved.

Comment: Good users can create good tags that are misused though. The [fit] tag probably started out with the best of intentions, but users who didn't pay attention to what the tag meant have clearly rendered the tag useless. There is no rep requirement for using existing tags. Yes, the community could have collectively avoided it by re-tagging these questions as they came up, but it is also a tag that I believe will continue to be consistently misused.