# Can we burninate the the desire to burninate?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-system

It seems that there is a significant amount of effort directed to burnination. Tags work by getting people who watch tags to look at questions. If a person uses a tag that does not apply to their question, or creates a tags that pertains to something vague, their question loses the opportunity to be seen by qualified people.

If people misuse tags, that's on them.

If a vague tag is being used, that's on them.

If people are watching a tag that is getting misused 40%+, that's on them.

If we stop trying to burninate, then we could suggest better tags for the OP to use next time in the comments. We could edit the post to use the correct tag. We could even create tags we think would work better.

Comment: Tag burnination arises from two motivations: the desire for tags to be semantically meaningful, and the desire to reduce noise, which bad tags unquestionably are.  I personally think that, if we're to pursue a better tag taxonomy, then we need better tools, but I do understand why there is built-in friction (tags must be removed one at a time from questions).

Comment: If you mean [anything like this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254594/707111), then no, thank you.

Comment: Most burnination requests I see are for tags that have very few followers.

Comment: "We could edit the post to use the correct tag" - that's how burnination normally works. You replace a misused, ambiguous or overly broad tag with better ones. So one of your replacement ideas for burnination is actually just a different description for the same thing?

Answer (score 20):

No. We can't burninate the desire to burninate. Culling tags is an important part of keeping Stack Overflow clean and usable.  We may hate the act of pulling weeds, but we appreciate the end-result.

One of the things that makes Stack Overflow useful is that we try not to leave cruft hanging around. Instead of putting up large warning signs (which we still do some of, unfortunately), we have tools in place to actively keep the site healthy, and not let rot sink in.

Keeping tags useful and well-scoped is a part of keeping the site looking good and staying healthy.

It's not about it "Being on them", it's about reinforcing the good practices, and getting rid of the bad ones. It's what separates us from forums, and animals (not unrelated, metaphorically speaking).